# VirtualFolder plugin does not seem to work in Resizer 3.2.2

Tags: imageresizer

When I call the url `http://localhost:15312/images/test.png?width=100` in Visual Studio Web server (I also tried Webmatrix) I get:

```
Source may only be an instance of string, VirtualFile, IVirtualBitmapFile, HttpPostedFile, HttpPostedFileBase, Bitmap, Image, or Stream.
Parameter name: source
```

Output of /resizer.debug:

```
Image resizer diagnostic sheet      2012-06-30 12:51:10

2 Issues detected:

(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use

(Warning):  Potentially incompatible ImageResizer assemblies were detected.
            Please make sure all ImageResizer assemblies are from the same version. Compatibility issues are possible if you mix plugins from different releases.
            1.0.0 assemblies: ImageResizerTest
            3.2.2 assemblies: ImageResizer, ImageResizer.Mvc


You are not using any paid bundles.

Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.VirtualFolder

Configuration:

<resizer>
<diagnostics enableFor="AllHosts" />
<plugins>
<add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
<add name="VirtualFolder" virtualPath="~/images" physicalPath="Media/Images" vpp="false" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom, 

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi, 

Environment information:

Running Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR 4.0.30319.269
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe
IntegratedPipeline: False

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.269   Info: 4.0.30319.269
System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.272   Info: 4.0.30319.272
System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.269   Info: 4.0.30319.269
System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Microsoft.Build.Framework                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.30319.1    Info: 10.0.30319.1
CppCodeProvider                          Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.30319.1    Info: 10.0.30319.1
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20505.0    
System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20505.0    
System.Web.Http.WebHost                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20505.0    
System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20505.0    
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20505.0    
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407  
System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
App_global.asax.104g7ahn                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
ImageResizerTest                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
WebDev.WebHost40                         Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.40219.1    Info: 10.0.40219.1
System.Web.Http                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20505.0    
System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.272   Info: 4.0.30319.272
Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.282   Info: 4.0.30319.282
System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.2.2.0         File: 3.2.2.0         Info: 3-2-beta-2  Commit: 3704dd6
ImageResizer.Mvc                         Assembly: 3.2.2.0         File: 3.2.2.0         Info: 3-2-beta-2  Commit: 3704dd6
Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5.1.14720    
System.Net.Http                          Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
System.Net.Http.Formatting               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.20505.0    
System.Net.Http.WebRequest               Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0        
System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20505.0    
System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 2.0.0.0         File: 2.0.20505.0    
System.Web.Routing                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Web.Abstractions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0        
System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
System.Xaml                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: It's a bug; set vpp back to true to avoid it until 3.2.3 is released.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried with vpp="true" and also removing the attribute but get same error. Guess I can revert back to 3.2.1 until I wait for the new 3.2.3.

Comment: Try this hotfix: http://downloads.imageresizing.net/Resizer3-2-beta-3-min-hotfix-2pm-Jun-30-2012.zip  Let me know if you can reproduce the problem again; I want to make sure we're talking about the same bug here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you for reporting this bug!**

This bug primarily affected users who had changed vpp="false" for the VirtualFolder installation, but also affected users on UNC paths and certain other scenarios.

**It has been fixed in [release 3.2.3 (changelog)](http://imageresizing.net/releases/3-2-beta-3)**.

You can [find the latest download here](http://imageresizing.net/download).